# Wordpress grab page attributes

Tags: wordpress

Is there a Wordpress function for grabbing the page attributes? I need to be able to check which templates are being used on which pages.

I have tried the get_post and get_pages but neither one outputs the page attributes.

Thanks in advance!

solution:

```
$ids= get_all_page_ids();

foreach ($ids as $id){ 
    $meta = get_metadata('post', $id);
    //var_dump($meta);
    $template = $meta['_wp_page_template'][0];
    echo $template;
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [`get_all_metadata`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_metadata). That will fetch all the meta records for a given object.

```
<?php
$post_id = 123;
$meta = get_metadata('post', $post_id);
echo $meta['my_custom_field_key'];
```

Answer (score 1):

The docs are a good place to look: [Function Reference « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference)

i.e.: [Function Reference/get page template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_template) which

> Displays the filename of the page template used to render a Page
>   (printed within an HTML comment, in this example) :
>
> `<?php echo '<!-- ' . basename( get_page_template() ) . ' -->'; ?>`

And,

```
global $wp_query;

$template_name = get_post_meta( $wp_query->post->ID, '_wp_page_template', true );
```

will give you the template file name. Use `str_replace()` to strip the .php from the end.
`